# How to split GPS data in python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, gps

I'm trying to split some data from a GPS module. The module prints GPS coordinates using multiple types. I need to be able to split the data type this starting with $ from the integers/other string later in that row.

```
#read in data
data = pd.read_fwf('/home/harry/Desktop/catTest')
#convert to csv file
data.to_csv('GPS.csv')
X = pd.read_csv('GPS.csv')
#Keep all values
GPS = X.iloc[:].values
#Test on random string 
Test_string = GPS[5,:]
#seperate string and int
result = [x.strip() for x in Test_string.split(',')]
print(Test_string)
print(result)


AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I want to print each item in the row on seperate rows.

How can I fix this?

This is what the 5th row item looks like when printed.

```
[5 '$GPTXT,01,01,02,LLC FFFFFFFF-FFFFFFFF-FFFFFFFF-FFFFFFFF-FFFFFFFD*2C']
```

Comment: You might want to use a Python library that does all the NMEA parsing like [pynmea2](https://github.com/Knio/pynmea2)

Answer (score 0):

```
data = pd.read_fwf('/home/harry/Desktop/catTest')
data.to_csv('GPS.csv')
X = pd.read_csv('GPS.csv')
#Keep all values
GPS = X.iloc[:].values
#Test on random string 
Test_string = GPS[5,:]
#seperate string and int
result = Test_string.apply(lambda x: x.split())
print(Test_string)
print(result)
```

you are selecting ndarray while spliting data try selecting single data while spliting data using lambda